# getting null location from network in android

Tags: android, location

I want to get the location from a network and save it in sqlite. Unfortunately I'm always getting the value of longitude and latitude as 0.0. I'm unable to find out the problem although I'm able to connect to wifi.
This is the method including a button which calls the location method class:

```
public void ButtonClick(View V) {
     gps = new GPSTracker(this);
    if (usersqlite_obj.RecvDate(DateOnly,shift)) {
    Common.ShowDialogue(this, "Warning", "Your data has already been saved");
   } else
     {
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();

    usersqlite_obj.open();

    usersqlite_obj.insertDAILYATTENDANCE(Recvdate, ffcode, terrcode,
            drcode, drname, addr, Recvdate, ffmgr, shift,
            Double.toString(latitude), Double.toString(longitude),
            droid_ref_no, SyncStatus,unique_droid_ref_no,DateOnly);
    usersqlite_obj.close();

    Intent i = null;
    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the GPSTracker class which I'm using to get the location.

```
 public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

     private final Context mContext;
     boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
     boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
     boolean canGetLocation = false;
     Location location; 
     double latitude; 
     double longitude; 
     private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; 
     private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; 
     protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
          return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have set these permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Have you enable the GPS from settings ?

Comment: I don't need gps, see the code i'm only using network

Comment: where are you testing/deploying this application ? in real device or in emulator ?

Comment: I'm testing on both emulator and real device

Comment: ok, does your device connected via Wifi properly ?

Comment: yes emulator and device is connected to wifi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82175/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-anita).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that you have have to wait for an update via

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{ 
  // then get the gps coordinated from 
     curlat  = if(loc.hasLatitude())loc.getLatitude();
     curlong = if(loc.hasLongitude())loc.getLongitude();
}
```

whereas you are asking for the variables before location update is recieved, hence it will always be null. Also you should check if loc has a value before getting it

Answer (score 0):

I have completed task use this api:

http://ip-api.com/json

This will give you your current location from your IP address very simply just call this JSON and you got whatever you required. 
Thanks

Comment: It seems interesting, i'm completely new in android can u explain more about this json or could you give me sample code for better understanding

Comment: http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-using-gps-network-provider/     try this code. i hope it is Helpfull to you.